# How to move Rails Engine's route to rails main routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-routing, rails-engines

I'm using Rails 4.2 with Rails Engine to handle my admin panel. I want to move the engine code to the main rails app and part of doing that is moving the routes.

For now, my routes in the Engine `my-web-app/lib/admin/config/routes.rb` is something like:

```
Admin::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :countries, only: [:index]
end
```

And at my app's routes `config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  .. some routes ...
  mount GlobalAdmin::Engine => "/admin"
end
```

Now the engine's route for countries is `countries_url` **NOT** `admin_countries_url` but for URL you'll need to access it with something like `admin/countries` (this is the default behavior for the engine and I want to keep it this way).

What I did is that I moved `my-web-app/lib/admin/config/routes.rb` to `my-web-app//config/routes.admin.rb` and made it look something like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :countries, only: [:index]
end
```

And then in my `config/application.rb` I added something like this:

```
config.paths["config/routes.rb"] = [
  Rails.root.join("config/routes.admin.rb"),
  Rails.root.join("config/routes.rb")
]
```

The problem with this approach is that I have `countries_url`, however, I can't access it with admin namespace URL like `admin/countries`. If I add namespace `admin` something like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :countries, only: [:index]
  end
end
```

Then I'll need to refer to countries url with `admin_countries_url` which is not the behavior I need.

Any help of how to move the routes from the engine without affecting the previous engine routes?

I'm aware that routes inside an engine are isolated from the application by default. The application and its engines can have routes with the same names, so integrating both can cause some issues, however I want to preserve the exact routes if possible and not to add a namespace and stick with the exact routes names.

Comment: Can you please just clearly state what the desired outcome is?

Comment: Sure, thanks for your willing to help @max. So with using my engine I have `countries_url` path name. Now with the refactoring and moving the route from the engine, I still want to have `countries_url` path. However just like in my previous implementation, I want the URL to look something like `admin/countries`.

Comment: If you have your engine routes something like: `Admin::Engine.routes.draw do; resources :countries, only: [:index];end` and it's mounted something like: `Rails.application.routes.draw do; mount GlobalAdmin::Engine => "/admin"; end`. Then we will end up with `countries_url` path and the URL can be accessed through `/admin/countries` and I want the exact same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-scope) instead of `namespace`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope path: "/admin" do
    resources :countries
  end
end
```

---

```
max@MaxBook ~/p/sandbox> rails routes
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                         Controller#Action
   countries GET    /admin/countries(.:format)          countries#index
             POST   /admin/countries(.:format)          countries#create
 new_country GET    /admin/countries/new(.:format)      countries#new
edit_country GET    /admin/countries/:id/edit(.:format) countries#edit
     country GET    /admin/countries/:id(.:format)      countries#show
             PATCH  /admin/countries/:id(.:format)      countries#update
             PUT    /admin/countries/:id(.:format)      countries#update
             DELETE /admin/countries/:id(.:format)      countries#destroy
```

Comment: Brilliant, this is EXACTLY what I'm looking for. Many thanks @max